# How to resolve runtime.cucumberexception for error parsing feature file

Tags: java, webdriver, cucumber, bdd

I just created simple java file which is used to execute the feature file through cucumber, but Its failed, and throws following run time exception

```
Exception in thread "main" cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: Error parsing feature file C:/Users/XXX/XXXX/src/test/java/RunTest.java
    at cucumber.runtime.FeatureBuilder.parse(FeatureBuilder.java:133)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberFeature.loadFromFeaturePath(CucumberFeature.java:102)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberFeature.load(CucumberFeature.java:54)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberFeature.load(CucumberFeature.java:34)
    at cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptions.cucumberFeatures(RuntimeOptions.java:201)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.run(Runtime.java:109)
    at cucumber.api.cli.Main.run(Main.java:36)
    at cucumber.api.cli.Main.main(Main.java:18)
Caused by: gherkin.lexer.LexingError: Lexing error on line 1: 'package test.java;

import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests;

    @CucumberOptions(features="src/test/resources/")
    public class RunTest extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {
    }
```

Feature file:

```
Feature: Search India on BBC website and verify search.

@Search
  Scenario Outline: Search India on BBC website and verify it.
    Given I open the firefox browser
    And I navigating to BBc website
    Then I click at search textbox
    And I enter "India" in search textbox
    And I click at Search button
    Then I should be taken to search page
    And I verify India on search page
```

Can somebody tell me how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When using a Scenario Outline, you need to provide an "Examples" section. In this case, it looks like you don't need a scenario outline at all, so:

```
Feature: Search India on BBC website and verify search.

  @Search
  Scenario: Search India on BBC website and verify it.
    Given I open the firefox browser
    And I navigating to BBc website
    Then I click at search textbox
    And I enter "India" in search textbox
    And I click at Search button
    Then I should be taken to search page
    And I verify India on search page
```

If you do need a scenario outline, you want something like:

```
Feature: Search India on BBC website and verify search.

  @Search
  Scenario Outline: Search India on BBC website and verify it.
    Given I open the firefox browser
    And I navigating to BBc website
    Then I click at search textbox
    And I enter "<country>" in search textbox
    And I click at Search button
    Then I should be taken to search page
    And I verify <country> on search page

  Examples:
    | country |
    | India   |
    | China   |
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you used "Scenario Outline" instead of "Scenario". So you just need to remove "Outline" than you are good to go.

```
@Search    
Scenario: Search India on BBC website and verify it
Given I open the firefox browser
And I navigating to BBc website
Then I click at search textbox
And I enter "India" in search textbox
And I click at Search button
Then I should be taken to search page
And I verify "India" on search page
```

But if you want to execute the same scenario against multiple input than you choose the right thing i.e. "Scenario Outline:" just need to add Examples there like:

```
@Search
  Scenario Outline: Search India on BBC website and verify it.
    Given I open the firefox browser
    And I navigating to BBc website
    Then I click at search textbox
    And I enter <country> in search textbox
    And I click at Search button
    Then I should be taken to search page
    And I verify <country> on search page
    Examples:
    | country |
    | "India" |
    | "UK"    |
```

Answer (score 0):

This was really useful.. I had the same error and after removing the space between the text Scenario and Colon. it would be useful if IDEshows the error to correct it ??
Scenario:
and no colon after Given Just to let you know.
Scenario Outline: Login with correct username and password
    Given I navigate to Login Page
    And  I enter < username > and < password >
    And  I click login button
    Then I should see the userform Page

```
Examples:
  | username                   | password  |

  | apple                      | passapple |
  | ball                       | passball  |
  | cat                        | passcat   |
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue .After removing the space between (:) semi colon and Feature, Scenario ,Scenario-outline etc.. My error resolved .

e.g :

```
Feature: Call all APIs Incidents, Services
     Scenario: Create POST call and verify data 
         Given user_has_a_list_of_products
         When we_can_get_a_list_of_product_details
```

and ,

```
    Feature: Call all APIs Incidents, Services
     Scenario Outline: Create POST call and verify data 
         Given user_has_a_list_of_products <usertype>
         When we_can_get_a_list_of_product_details

        Examples:
            | usertype     |
            | Domestic     |
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the below scenario -

`Feature: Booking Confirmation Page
 Scenario: Verify the Page components
    Given that a customer is on the "BookingConfirmation" page
    When the customer views the Page
    Then they should be able to view the following :
      | Header | BookingId | Passengers name | Date of travel | Time of travel | 
      |Bus details | Total amount paid |Destination name|Destination Image|
      |Time to reach destination | Footer|`

If you specify the values to verify in 2nd line as shown it will give a parse error. When you copy the above and paste in the editor it will not show you any error. But when you run it it will give the parse error. So we need to specify the value to verify in a single line even if it doesn't fit in the editor

So the scenario will be as below

`Scenario: Verify the Page components
    Given that a customer is on the "BookingConfirmation" page
    When the customer views the Page
    Then they should be able to view the following :
      | Header | BookingId | Passengers name | Date of travel | Time of travel | Bus details | Total amount paid |Destination name|Destination Image|Time to reach destination |Footer|`

Answer (score 0):

make sure you only have word Feature once

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this issue. In my case, I missed one pipe '|' in one of my data table. after adding it, issue resolved. data table (or sometime in Example)

```
Issue:
      | feed.title            |
      | feed.updated          
      | feed.author.name      |

Corrected(added pipe in 2nd data) as:
      | feed.title            |
      | feed.updated          |
      | feed.author.name      |
```

Answer (score 0):

I got same error message, then I realized that someone add comment to the gherkin step using `//`. It should be using `#`

Answer (score 0):

Resolved this issue after added the missing pipe symbol.